# Can someone show me the correct "Hello World" on ROS?

Tags: python, ros

As a very beginner on ROS, I am trying to produce the minimum code for printing "Hello World" on the screen. My Python version: 3.8, operating system: Ubuntu, ROS system: Noetic.
This is the simple code I tried:

```
import rospy
if --name-- == "--main--":
   print("hello world")
```

after entering in the terminal:

```
 runros mypackagename helloWorld.py
```

error messages come up: import command not found, syntax error unexpected token '"hello world"'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
First I had forgotten the header code in the first line, and then I forgot to add the 3 for the correct python version.
So, the correct hallo world code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Hello World!')
```

Thank you @BTables, for pointing out the syntax error of the double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to import `rospy` for this and your error is caused by a syntax issue. It should be

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Hello World!')
```

When using and importing `rospy` make sure you have run `source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash` first. As well, your command for running the script is wrong. It should be `rosun` not `runros`

Comment: Thanks, BTables. I took away the import and I corrected the syntax errors as you showed, but I still get the same errors. I then further simplified my test by replacing the print command with this simple statement: x = 3 The compiler now reported: unexpected end of file. I recreated the file, this time with the Vi editor to make sure the file is clean. Same result.

Comment: @Aguilo you are running something incorrectly then, because the above syntax in my answer is correct. How are you building the ROS package?

Comment: After creating a workspace called "myworkspace" by means of the catkin_make command, I created a package called "mypackage" by means of the catkin_create_pkg command. 
In the scripts directory, I created helloworld.py and made it executable with chmod +x.
I have run: source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash. 
When I run rosrun myworkspace helloworld.py I get the
error message: syntax error near unexpected token `'Hello World!''

Comment: @Aguilo If that's the exact error you're getting you have mistyped something. You're mixing 3 different quotation marks there.

Comment: Hi, @BTables. No, my spelling was OK, I had copy-pasted it from you, but I had forgotten to write: #!/usr/bin/python in the head of the file. Adding this, solved the error and the interpreter now comes with the message: line 150: home/rolf/myworkspace/src/mypackage/scripts/helloworld.py: Success. However, it still doesn't print Hello World on the screen, so apparently, there is still something missing in my script, but the error is gone. –